# Agregar por defecto que la app sea protected app in Huawei atravez del codigo en ionic 3

Tags: ionic, cordova

No me llegan las notificaciones cuando la app está cerrada porque huawei no tiene la app activada en gestor de teléfono -> protected apps. ¿Existe alguna forma por ahí en el config.xml de agregar una tag que la haga protected por defecto?

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es debido a Ionic, el usuario debe autorizar al Administrador del Sistema proteger la aplicación en segundo plano, si queres hacer la pregunta te tocaría hacer uso del plugin `cordova-plugin-intent` y hacer una petición al sistema en el paquete `com.huawei.systemmanager` su clase `com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity`.

Ref: [Ejemplo en StackOverflow en Inglés para Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it) y [Plugin Cordova Intent en Github](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent).